# How can i minimize the memory leak/stack-buffer-overflow errors like this?

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a problem on Codeforces, I am trying to count the number of letters i have to remove so that no two neighbours have same alphabet.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<algorithm>


 int main(){

    int n,count=0,i=0,j=1;
    std::cin>>n;
    std::string s;
    std::cin>>s;
    if(n==1){
      std::cout<<count;
    }
    else {
      while(n--||s[j]){
        if(s[i]==s[j]){
          count++;
          j++;
        }
        else {
          i=j;
          j=j+1;
        }
      }
      std::cout<<count;
   }

   return 0;

}
```

I got runtime error.
Diagnostics detected issues [cpp.clang++-diagnose]: =================================================================

> ==2064==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x1184f938 at pc 0x010a148f bp 0x1184f8f4 sp 0x1184f8f0 READ of size 1
>   at 0x1184f938 thread T0
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_symbolizer_win.cc:64
>   "((dbghelp && "failed to load dbghelp.dll")) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)
>   ==2064==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: C:\src\llvm_package_600-final\llvm\projects\compiler-rt\lib\sanitizer_common\sanitizer_win.cc:795
>   "((owner_)) == ((LOCK_READY))" (0xe14, 0xffffffff)

Comment: What is `n`? The length of the input string?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for not clarifying it. i and j are for indexing. Count is the number of removals needed so that two neighbours are not same.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I will. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
while(n--||s[j])
```

Now if `n` is the length of the string, then `s[j]` will result in an out-of-bounds memory access because `j` is always incremented in the `while` loop.

Take the simple case when the string is "me" and `n` is `2`. `s[2]` is not a legal access.

Comment: Thanks. This was the mistake.